# NullPointerException Minecraft MCP Forge 1.6 when adding crops?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm making a minecraft mod in Minecraft MCP Forge 1.6(not sure whether to put this in the gaming section or not) and I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when I load the game.

Here is the code:
Main: http://pastebin.com/w8i0p46d

```
package net.minecraft.MFM;

import net.minecraft.MSM.eventmanager;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemFood;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemSeedFood;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.potion.Potion;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.Init;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.network.NetworkMod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.network.NetworkRegistry;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.LanguageRegistry;
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.Side;
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;

@Mod(modid = morefoodmod.modid, name = "More Food Mod", version = "0.1")
@NetworkMod(clientSideRequired = true, serverSideRequired = false)

public class morefoodmod {
    public static final String modid = "morefoodmod";
    @Instance("morefoodmod")
    public static morefoodmod instance = new morefoodmod();

    // public static CommonProxy proxy;

    @Init
    public void initMain(FMLInitializationEvent e) {
        // NetworkRegistry.instance().registerGuiHandler(this, new guiHandler());
    }
    public static CreativeTabs mfmTab;
    public static Block BlockStrawberry;
    public static Item ItemHealingApple;
    public static Item ItemRegenApple;
    public static Item ItemStrawberry;

    eventmanager eventmanager = new eventmanager();

    @EventHandler
    public void load(FMLInitializationEvent e) {
        mfmTab = new CreativeTabs("mfmTab") {
             @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
             public Item getTabItemIconIndex() {
                 return Item.fishCooked;
             }
        };
        LanguageRegistry.instance().addStringLocalization(mfmTab.getTranslatedTabLabel(), "More Food Mod");
        ItemHealingApple = new HealingApple(5371, 4, 2F, false).setPotionEffect(Potion.regeneration.id, 1, 255, 1.0F).setUnlocalizedName("itemHealingApple");
        ItemRegenApple = new RegenApple(8029, 4, 2F, false).setPotionEffect(Potion.regeneration.id, 300, 1, 1F).setUnlocalizedName("itemRegenApple");
        // Exception thrown on the following statement.
        ItemStrawberry = new ItemSeedFood(7231, 3, 0.5F, BlockStrawberry.blockID, Block.tilledField.blockID).setUnlocalizedName("itemStrawberry").setTextureName(modid + ":" + "itemStrawberry").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabFood);
        BlockStrawberry = new Strawberry(1018).setUnlocalizedName("blockStrawberry");
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ItemHealingApple, 1), new Object[]{"GPG", "DAD", "GPG", 'G', Item.ingotGold, 'D', Item.diamond, 'A', Item.appleRed, 'P', new ItemStack(Item.potion, 1, 8261)});
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ItemRegenApple, 1),new Object[]{"GPG", "DAD", "GPG", 'G', Item.ingotGold, 'D', Item.diamond, 'A', Item.appleRed, 'P', new ItemStack(Item.potion, 1, 8193)});

        registerBlock(BlockStrawberry, "StrawberryGrow");
        registerItem(ItemStrawberry, "Strawberry");
        registerItem(ItemHealingApple, "Healing Apple");
        registerItem(ItemRegenApple ,"Regeneration Apple");
    }
    public void registerItem(Item item, String name){
        GameRegistry.registerItem(item, item.getUnlocalizedName());
        LanguageRegistry.addName(item, name);
    }
    public void registerBlock(Block block, String name){
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(block, block.getUnlocalizedName());
        LanguageRegistry.addName(block, name);
    }
}
```

Strawberry: http://pastebin.com/7qC4DkNt

```
package net.minecraft.MFM;

import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.Side;
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.BlockCrops;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.IconRegister;
import net.minecraft.util.Icon;

public class Strawberry extends BlockCrops {
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    private Icon[] iconArray;

    protected Strawberry(int par1) {
        super(par1);
    }

    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    public Icon getIcon(int side, int metadata) {
        if(metadata > 7) {
            if(metadata == 6)
                    metadata = 5;
            return iconArray[metadata >> 1];
        }
        return iconArray[3];
    }
    public int getSeedItem() {
            return morefoodmod.ItemStrawberry.itemID;
    }
    public int getCropItem() {
            return morefoodmod.ItemStrawberry.itemID;
    }
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    public void registerIcons(IconRegister iconRegister) {
        this.iconArray = new Icon[4];

        for(int i = 0; i < this.iconArray.length; i++)
            this.iconArray[i] = iconRegister.registerIcon(morefoodmod.modid + ":" + "itemStrawberry_" + (i+1));
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Don't try to access an object that is null. You need to find which object is null and then be sure that it is initialized somewhere before that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an object before actually initialised it:

```
ItemStrawberry = new ItemSeedFood(7231, 3, 0.5F, BlockStrawberry.blockID, Block.tilledField.blockID).setUnlocalizedName("itemStrawberry").setTextureName(modid + ":" + "itemStrawberry").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabFood);
BlockStrawberry = new Strawberry(1018).setUnlocalizedName("blockStrawberry");
```

`BlockStrawBerry` should be initialised for `ItemStrawberry`.